# Records in SQL Server view are not showing up in Power BI query

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery

I want to get all the rows in a SQL Server view inside Power BI Power Query.

I have data about employees assigned to new projects, it stored in a SQL Server view, and it contains 13,474 rows. The view is based on master and detail tables.

One of the columns in the view is named `project_effective_date`, I am using it inside power query to validate the pulled records, and it contains old and new project effective dates for the years 2015, 2016, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023.

I have connected to this view from Power Query using direct mode in one Power BI file and import mode in another one.

The issue that I am experiencing is from the 13,470 records only 7,148 records have been pulled inside the power query in both Power BI files (direct mode & import mode).

- I have validated the number of records in power query by using "count values" option in statistics option in power query on a primary key column `transaction_number` which has no null values.
- Also, I have noticed that all records belong to `project_effective_date = 2023`, and some records from other `project_effective_dates` are not showing up.
- Also, I have added a "clustered bar chart" visual to display the number of employees by project in 2023, but the visual is display nothing.
- Also, I have executed a the below query against the view to count the number of employees by year and this is the result

```
SELECT 
    COUNT([EffectiveDate]) AS [number_of_employyes],
    datepart(yyyy, [EffectiveDate]) as [year]
FROM 
    [dbo].[BIView_ChangeOverForms]
WHERE 
    DATEPART(yyyy, [EffectiveDate]) IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(yyyy, [EffectiveDate])
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(yyyy, [EffectiveDate]) ASC
```

| number_of_employyes | year |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 2015 |
| 17 | 2016 |
| 2010 | 2020 |
| 4725 | 2021 |
| 5235 | 2022 |
| 1453 | 2023 |

The total number of employees in the view is 13,470.

- Also, I have grouped the records in power query to count the number of employees by year and this is the result

| number_of employees | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 2015 |
| 17 | 2016 |
| 1995 | 2020 |
| 4737 | 2021 |
| 368 | 2022 |

The total number of employees in the power query = 7,147.

I have compared the total umber of employees from view and Power Query
missed records: 13,470 - 7,147 = 6.319

**Note:** there's no filter applied on any column in power query. And I have updated Power BI to the latest version

Comment: please post your power query code. it might also be helpful to see the top N of your SQL query as opposed to the output of said power query.

Comment: Are you using Power BI Premium or Power BI Embedded? Those have a query caching facility available that will cache results on a per-user basis from the first time a query executes. Ref: [Query caching in Power BI Premium or Power BI Embedded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-query-caching)

Comment: Aside... the `date` data type in SQL Server cannot ever be incomplete, so instead of `WHERE datepart(yyyy, [EffectiveDate]) IS NOT NULL`  consider instead `WHERE [EffectiveDate] IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Dolunaykiz here is the power query code

`let
    Source = Sql.Databases("123.45.6.7"),
    BIView_DW = Source{[Name="BIView"]}[Data],
    dbo_BIView_ChangeOverForms = BIView{[Schema="dbo",Item="BIView_ChangeOverForms"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_BIView_ChangeOverForms, each ([NewProject] <> "Test Proj2" and [NewProject] <> "TestProj1") and ([OldProject] <> "Test Proj2"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"`

Comment: I am using Power BI Pro